# How to use ng if else in one html tag to derive the condition

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if

Can anyone help me solving the below issue, Currently I am using below code to display the values where i am using the two `<td>` tags derive the conditional values , Is there any way I can do kind of else in one `<td>` tag?

```
<td class="features" ng-if="OrderStatus.length>0">
<span ng-repeat="indi in ServiceDisconnects.Service">{{indi.serviceID}}<br></span>
</td>

<td class="features" ng-if="!OrderStatus.length>0">
<span ng-repeat="indi in ServiceDisconnects.Service">{{indi.productID}}<br></span>
</td>
```

Comment: Whats the point of doing so in the given example. In each case, you have displayed the same product id.

Comment: @TNC `{{indi.serviceID}}` and `{{indi.productID}}` are different Since I want that `td` element should take either servieID or productID based on the condition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why dont you check it inside ng-repeat

```
<td ng-repeat="indi in ServiceDisconnects.Service">
<span ng-if="OrderStatus.length>0" >{{indi.serviceID}}<br></span>
<span ng-if="!OrderStatus.length>0" >{{indi.serviceID}}<br></span>
</td>
```

Comment: Wow One more time u saved me @sajeetharan Accepted the answer

Answer (score 4):

Just add your condition in expression({{}})

```
<td ng-repeat="indi in ServiceDisconnects.Service">
<span>{{ OrderStatus.length>0? indi.serviceID:indi.productID}}</span><br>
</td>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what you are looking for. Modify as per your need.

```
<td class="features" >
    <span ng-repeat="indi in ServiceDisconnects.Service">
    <span ng-if="OrderStatus.length>0">{{indi.serviceID}}</span>
    <span ng-if="!OrderStatus.length>0">{{indi.productID}}</span>
    <br></span>
</td>
```